# List the most popular pages in a SilverStripe site

Tags: php, silverstripe

How do we list the most popular (most viewed) pages in SilverStripe?

I would like to list the most viewed blog posts in a site.

I tried the [following code](http://www.inforbiro.com/blog-eng/silverstripe-most-popular-articles/), but it is not working:

```
public function MostPopularBlogArticles($num = 5) { 
    return DataObject::get(
        "BlogPostPage",
        "Status = 'Published'",
        "`PageCounter`.Counter DESC",
        "INNER JOIN PageCounter ON `PageCounter`.PageID = `BlogPostPage`.ID",
    $num
    );
}
```

Template:

```
<ul>
    <% control MostPopularBlogArticles(5) %>
    <li>
        <a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a>
    </li>
    <% end_control %>
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to improve your question. I have added the code from the link, but can you please edit this to show exactly what code you tried. Did you also add the page view counter code from the link in that article? If so add that into your question. Did you update this code / templating for the latest version of SilverStripe? What blog module are you using? Try to fill in information like this in your questions to help the community to help you.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my question :) , i use the latest version of blog addon [Link](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog)

Comment: yes i use the page view counter but i have never use and seen like this `->innerJoin('PageView', '`BlogPost`.`ID` = `PageView`.`PageID`')` Thanks for your help i'll try it again on your code structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is based off the [SilverStripe CMS Page Hit/View Counter](http://www.inforbiro.com/blog-eng/silverstripe-cms-page-hit-view-counter/) and 
[SilverStripe - Most Popular Articles](http://www.inforbiro.com/blog-eng/silverstripe-most-popular-articles/) blog posts on the Infobiro website. These instructions are for SilverStripe 3.4 using the current version of the [SilverStripe blog module](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog).

First we create a `PageView` `DataObject` to keep track of the page count for each page.

```
class PageView extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Count' => 'Int'
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Page' => 'Page'
    );
}
```

In our `Page` class we create a `$belongs_to` relationship  to `PageView`so that we can easily retrieve the related `PageView` object.

```
class Page extends SiteTree {

    private static $belongs_to = array(
        'PageView' => 'PageView'
    );

}
```

In our `Page_Controller` `init` function we increment the page view count. This will get called each time the page is accessed on the front end by a user. First we retrieve or create the related `PageView` count. Then we increment the `Count` value.

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {

    public function init() {
        parent::init();

        $pageView = $this->PageView();

        if (!$pageView) {
            $pageView = PageView::create();
            $pageView->PageID = $this->ID;
            $pageView->write();

        }

        $pageView->Count = $pageView->Count + 1;
        $pageView->write();
    }
}
```

In `Page_Controller` we also create a `MostViewedBlogPosts` to fetch a list of the most viewed `BlogPosts`.

```
class Page_Controller extends ContentController {
    // ...

    public function MostViewedBlogPosts($limit = 5) {
        return BlogPost::get()
            ->innerJoin('PageView', '`BlogPost`.`ID` = `PageView`.`PageID`')
            ->sort('PageView.Count', 'DESC')
            ->limit($limit);
    }
}
```

This function can easily be changed to fetch a list of any page type. For example to get a list of most viewed pages:

```
public function MostViewedPages($limit = 5) {
    return Page::get()
        ->innerJoin('PageView', '`Page`.`ID` = `PageView`.`PageID`')
        ->sort('PageView.Count', 'DESC')
        ->limit($limit);
}
```

In our template we retrieve the `MostViewedBlogPosts` list as follows:

```
<% if $MostViewedBlogPosts %>
    <ul>
    <% loop $MostViewedBlogPosts %>
        <li><a href="$Link">$Title</a></li>
    <% end_loop %>
    </ul>
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: It's work, thanks but how to remove duplicate blogpost?

Comment: I don't think there should be any duplicates. Are you sure they are the same page? Change `<a href="$Link">$Title</a>` to `<a href="$Link">$Title - $ID</a>` to see if the duplicates have the same `ID`. If they are different IDs then they are different pages with the same content.

Comment: @Misagh90 what about the above code doesn't work for SS4?